# When the ref view is gone, how to keep the position of the ref view's start

Tags: android, xml, layout, view, android-constraintlayout

I have like this [layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLFur.png).
The problem is approve button need to locate on start of detail button.
But sometimes, detail button is gone. or approve and reject buttons are gone.
Then, how can I keep these button's position...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/detailButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/skyblue"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="show more detail ->"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/rejectButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/approveButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/skyblue"
        android:text="approve"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/detailButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/detailButton" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/rejectButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/skyblue"
        android:text="reject"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/detailButton" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to make the visibility of the buttons [invisible](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#attr_android:visibility):

> **invisible    Not displayed, but taken into account during layout (space is left for it).**

For invisible views, the view still occupies its allotted space, but does not show.